The WP Plugin Review team asked me to review a line of code I wish to submit in the WP Plugin Repository?
I have designed a plugin where recent posts can be shown in a tabbed format where category names are the tab heads. The WP Plugin Review team asked me for a review of the following line of code. Not sure what went wrong here. Thank you.
My line of Code
<li class="tab-switcher" <?php echo ($atts['font_family'] != "disabled") ? 'style="font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;"' : ''?>>
     <span onclick="clickTabHead(event, '<?php echo esc_js($category->slug);?>')"  class="catname <?php if($count==1){echo esc_js('active');}?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo esc_js($category->name);?></span>
     </li>

Comment by the Review Team
Remember: You must use the most appropriate functions for the context. There is pretty much an option for everything you could echo. Even echoing HTML safely.
tabbed-posts/tabbed_posts.php:64: <span onclick="clickTabHead(event, '<?php echo $category->slug;')" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $category->name;</span>
tabbed-posts/tabbed_posts.php:83: <div id="<?php echo $category->slug;">


I think the problem is that you use esc_js for the category name despite it's not in javascript code.

All the uses for esc_js in the code are inappropriate. It's meant for escaping Javascript code but you use it for escaping JS strings, CSS classes and HTML content.

The issue with your code is primarily about security and proper coding standards. Here's what the WordPress Plugin Review team likely flagged:
Wrong Escaping:
You're using esc_js() in places where it's not appropriate. For HTML attributes like data-category-slug, use esc_attr(). For text displayed on the page, use esc_html().
Inline JavaScript:
Avoid using inline onclick attributes. WordPress encourages separating JavaScript from HTML to improve security and maintainability.
Here’s a better version of your code:
<li class="tab-switcher" <?php echo ($atts['font_family'] !== "disabled") ? 'style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;"' : ''; ?>>
<span 
    class="catname <?php echo ($count === 1) ? 'active' : ''; ?>" 
    role="tab" 
    data-toggle="tab" 
    data-category-slug="<?php echo esc_attr($category->slug); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_html($category->name); ?>
</span>


Changes I made:
Used esc_attr() for data-category-slug to properly escape it for an attribute.
Used esc_html() to securely output the category name.
Removed the onclick attribute. Instead, you can handle the click event with JavaScript separately.
This should address their concerns and make your code safer and more compliant with WordPress standards.
